# Fork repeats twice?

Tags: c, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    int rval, pid;

    pid = fork();
    switch(pid)
    {
        case -1:
            printf("I am bad.\n");

        case 0:
            printf("I am in child.\n");
            rval = a + b;
            printf("leaving child.\n");
        default:
            wait();
            printf("I am back to parent.\n");
            //wait();
            printf("%d \n", rval);
            printf("leaving parent.\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting child statements first, then parents. But there shouldn't be any reptition. Instead,

```
>> ./demo
I am in child.
leaving child.
I am back to parent.
2 
leaving parent.
I am back to parent.
134513584 
leaving parent.
```

Parent is repeated twice. Why is that?
Furthermore, how did parent get `2` from the child? Child's has its own virtual memory for `a` and `b` so how did we transfer that result to parent?
I am confused.

---

Further investigation
When I insert `return 0` into the `case 0`, it will not repeat. It looks like the switch statement continues. Did I miss something about switch statement?

Comment: Switch statement fall-through ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C, switch statements fall through cases by default; you have to put a `break;` (or `return`) statement at the end of each case, otherwise, e.g., the child will execute both the child and the parent code.

Comment: Ah Right. I am totally so stunned. I haven't used switch for a long time. Thanks. I found out that just a minute ago as well. That was the mystery to why I got `2`.

Answer (score 6):

You have no `break` statements in your cases, and so each case falls through to the next. The child, with `pid == 0`, will execute both the *0* and *default* case blocks.

Answer (score 0):

As fork returns two pid's one to parent process and other to child process, for parent it returns > 0 `pid` and for child returns 0 as pid. Hence case for 0 gets executed but there is `no break` so default is also executed because in absence of break statement switch case falls through....

Comment: What do you think that your answer adds to the ones that already have been given? And why is this formatted so weirdly?